# Extended version of the theory of reals and its decidability

Tags: logic, computability

It is well-known due to Tarski that the theory of reals $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,<,=)$ is decidable. I was asking my self whether one would lose the decidability by adding all real constants. More formally, is the theory $(\mathbb{R},\{\underline{r} \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\} +,\cdot,<,=)$ evaluated in the standard model of the reals decidable? Here, the symbol $\underline{r}$ is such that its interpretation in the standard model is exactly the real $r$.

I guess that this is the case, essentially because two reals are different if and only if there exists a rational number between them. Rationals, on the other hand, can be expressed in the usual Tarski fragment.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Presumably we are adding to the axioms for real-closed fields the complete diagram of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

There's the fundamental problem here that you have now defined a logical language *with uncountably many symbols*. This means that you also have uncountably many different *formulas*, which means that you have no way of encoding all formulas uniquely in a way that can be input to a Turing machine.

Therefore it doesn't really make sense to ask *whether* the theory is decidable -- or at least not without extending the meaning of "decidable" such that it can handle uncountable sets of inputs. And if you do that, it is doubtful how much your resulting notion of "decidable" will have to do with the usual one.

For example, your language has a symbol that corresponds to [Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant). It will take some extremely careful design to define a class of machines that can manipulate this symbol in a way that feels meaningful *without* having as a side effect that the halting problem suddenly becomes "decidable".

Comment: To say that the input domains are uncountable so they can't be inputs to a Turing machine is a little simplistic. The OP's formulas can be encoded as data streams as studied in [computable analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis). That may lead to some interesting possibilities that your answer doesn't cover.

Comment: ... E.g., a kind of decidability based on some form of approximated completeness  as discussed in http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4051

Comment: @RobArthan: Yeah ... but in the case that all we get is successive approximations (where we can only inspect finitely many before we have to give a true/false answer), not even formulas such as $\sigma^2>2$ (where $\sigma$ is one of the new constants) will be decidable.

Comment: In general if we have an ordinary Turing machine that is purported to decide truth in the extended language, and _this machine always terminates in finite time_, then even though infinitely many bits is _potentially_ available to the machine, there are only countably many different _runs_ of the machine. This means there must be countably many _classes_ of new constants where the machine treats everything in each class the same.

Comment: Computable analysis deals with non-terminating computations on streams (and the new constants would be communicated bit-by-bit as part of an input stream). In that context, it is reasonable to consider more general notions of completeness and decidability. I am not disagreeing with your answer to the original question viewed from a traditional point of view, but I am trying to point out that there are other meaningful takes on this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

By Theorem 1.1 on page 260 of the book, which is about 1/8 of the way

through [the pdf](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717110800033), the extended "version of the theory of reals" is decidable.